# How to remove quotation and symbols while decoding from JSON value? Flutter

Tags: flutter

**This is the code to get my auth token.**

```
Future <String> getToken() async{
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('token');

  }
```

**When i print the token it gives me this json value with double quotation mark.**

```
I/flutter (14710): "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiZDQzZjFjNWZjZDQxYjIzYzllNGU2ZWIyZjQ1M2FmZDgwOTJiNGZmNDAyYjI0OTBmM2RiYTUzMTgzYTU2ODZjNTNiNzVmMDY3ZmIzMmNjMjUiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTA0MDg2NjksIm5iZiI6MTU5MDQwODY2OSwiZXhwIjoxNjIxOTQ0NjY5LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.3YYdR8P1_XzK--VLAwT5gxmkyLZPMuvQhzQQ5OOl_nv0jriPwFY9sqHdL_wiqpAA5vtgBOnyAwZ2kSI_BgDzsKZzY2vMVa47Tyuz87uEFZ7-aHYvNY_r4T_gIkwAuLwc8qN2kuytFjEtuq-iQUiWgEzp5y2n3BDlzXZ7rZi5Xp1_y_6_ysII9RQtX37LuDFt3AIRbYLGDBAilPHi0iJB_jQqWqH8J1mUzCsArj2VuSel7kERqpwFz-SwOOS4EA7CaoOuOlleOpynBalTK9vm1vU3n81K4TAgNq-Mg9CsiFMVQULURdmku7-2gcc3VS8vBXo9OlEgzqmGjLDvIy8_-LCcwuoSVC2DL2t2PIcNUDKQsBu1GBPQ99wzHcnyEpvjVRkg7v4zQWtlIUY6PcLjNf_vnfuXuCERAwBwjS86T7n8ZscfmVVebISVvAKyDN6YhW41hnUw-AZYRLtuhbE8Z48V0tLfLw9aeVr-Qe2mlaYj0LqGYlqBLqUtRl9HSaA9USa6tQ1KQJvF5_6JPcIBJuSkEsrY9n1xhnCViAiyFVF4XWbtToULn69B2UtoXw1X8y_Wek_T7D7t0fi5KWKj8QHO6yI3ZIWViERS2K6n7mnL_3z_7CNeewVxmqMXNdeWl7yPmAMzUAv6z7pWm-R1Qpv7tNVj4-FfQAk3vOm56hE"
```

**This is how i used the token you get the post from api but it isnt working.**

```
     Future<Model> ViewWelcomeScreen() async {
    String url = '$baseurl/post/20';
   ApiService().getToken().then((value){
      token = value;
    });
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });
    print(token);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var test = json.decode(response.body);
      var jsonResponse = test['data'];
      return Model.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: can you show logs?

Comment: `I/flutter (14710): Exception: Failed to load data`
This is the error, it means that its unauthorized meaning it inst reading the token or the token has a symbol on the start.

Comment: it could be somthing else also. can you check the status code?

Comment: can you tell me what is a status code is.

Comment: http status code.

Comment: `The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<Model>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<Model>>#cec61):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length`

Comment: check my answer it's not about the code, and also not this error as you're not receiving 200 you're throwing error which again leads to null object and hence this length was called on null object.

if there's some other error do let me know. in comment.
also if it resolves the issue upvote and mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<Model> ViewWelcomeScreen() async {
    String url = '$baseurl/post/20';
   ApiService().getToken().then((value){
      token = value;
    });
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });
    print(token);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var test = json.decode(response.body);
      var jsonResponse = test['data'];
      return Model.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
```

code is wrong in a way, think you have async and then both on the same function, why?

```
ApiService().getToken().then((value){
      token = value;
    });
```

here you're saying I want token and I don't need to be awaited then you go and try to use that variable

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });
```

see in flutter every async-await works like event loop in javascript

1. I write async
2. normal code
3. using then in 1. function
4. dependent code in 1. as async-await

what will be the output?
event loop will be having 1,2,3,4 as async functions
first, it will run 1 and as soon as it receives normal code it runs normally but if it receives then it will understand that this result is not important so let me do rest of the work and will come back to execute 3rd then function so it will run 4 and then 3rd function

but you want token so

```
ApiService().getToken().then((value){
      token = value;
    });
```

replace this to

```
token = await ApiService().getToken();
```

your service might need token and that's the reason it's not 200 status code.

Comment: i did that at first but the issue is the same, it isn't reading the token.

Comment: print token is there any token? 
before calling API and also print else response.statuscode with response.error or response.data don't know in which variable it stores response but you need to print that also to understand the real issue

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the `""` from the string, then just use the `replaceAll` method

```
String string = '"foo"';

//Output: 'foo'
string.replaceAll('"', '');
```